# try to get var from each function jquery and work with insertbefore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get `div` id number and insert it before, here is my code:

```
$( "#container  div.mix" ).each(function( index ) {

if(index=='2'){  var id1=this.id  }

if(index=='3'){  var id21=this.id  }


if(index=='8'){  var id111=this.id  }
if(index=='9'){  var id21111=this.id  }


    $("#"+id1).insertBefore("#"+id21);
    $("#"+id111).insertBefore("#"+id21111);


});
```

My HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="mix" id="4"></div>
    <div class="mix" id="3"></div>
    <div class="mix" id="2"></div>
    <div class="mix" id="1"></div>
</div>
```

This isn't working because the each loop forget my var when I selected.

How can I get it to remember the variable so that I can use `insertBefore`?

Comment: please post your html code

Comment: i add it , sorry for forget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#container div.mix:eq(2)").insertBefore( jQuery("#container div.mix:eq(3)") );
```